# QLPreviewController load document from URL with basic authentication

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I want to use a `QLPreviewController` and load a file from an URL.

I use this delegate function to return the URL for the file i want to preview:

```
func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem
```

Now my fileURL is protected with basic authentication, how can i add this to the request?

Comment: Did you manage to sort it out?